# How to completely ignore Date from Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a start date and end date.
I want to calculate the time difference between the two, but without taking into account the Date.

```
var startTime = moment('02-01-2021 13:01:01'); {/* Mon Feb 01 2021 13:01:01 GMT+0100 */}
var endTime = moment('02-01-2022 17:01:01'); {/* Tue Feb 01 2022 17:01:01 GMT+0100 */}
```

If we only look at the Time, the difference between the two (in hours) is 8764.

```
endTime.diff(startTime,'hours')
```

My desired result would be 4.

Comment: Worth pointing out that moment is now officially deprecated https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: I guess what you can do is pass the same date and change only the time.
Something like:
var startTime = moment('02-01-2022 13:01:01'); 
var endTime = moment('02-01-2022 17:01:01');

Comment: format and convert back to a moment and take diff `moment(moment('02-01-2021 13:01:01').format("HH:mm"),"HH:mm")`